# Store all the links in a webpage as json data using jasmine js

Tags: javascript, json, jasmine, protractor, karma-jasmine

I'm looking to store all the links in a webpage as json data and then checking them for validity using jasmine js. But so far I haven't had any luck as I couldn't find a way to do it.

```
describe('savejson', function()
   {
    var map = new Map();
    it('save', function(myarg)
    {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys("java");
        browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//button[@name='btnG']")).click();
        map = browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//a[@href]"));
        console.log(map);
    });
   });
```

Is there any way to store it in a map or any other collection?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply store all the Links's in an array and use the result wherever required. Look at below example.

```
describe('savejson', function()
 {
     var urlList=[];
   it('save', function(myarg)
    {
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
      browser.driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
      browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys("java");
      browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//button[@name='btnG']")).click();
      urlList = browser.driver.findElements(by.xpath("//a[@href]"));
   });

   it('Should validate stored links',function(){
        urlList.each(function(linkElement,index){
              linkElement.click();
              browser.sleep(1000);
              expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('some URL'); // do whatever you need to assert
              browser.navigate().back();
              browser.sleep(1000);
         })
    })
 });
```

Comment: i tried using forEach, map, each but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Updated my answer!!

Comment: remove `getAttribute()` from line `urlList = browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//a[@href]"))`

Comment: Im sorry. we need to use `findElements` intead of `findelement`. `each` will work only for array.

Comment: A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
Failed: window is not defined

Comment: Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Comment: Failed: obj.each is not a function

Comment: i tried getting the urlList data on the console, but its blank.

Answer (score 0):

I think below the solution should work for you.

```
describe('savejson', function() {
it('save', function() {
    browser.driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
    browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys("java");
    browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//button[@name='btnG']")).click();
    var linksList = [];

    linksList = browser.driver.findElements(by.tagName("a"));

    var testDataLInks = ["www.www.com", "sss.sss.sss"];

    linksList.each(function(link) {
        link.getAttribute('href').then(function(hyperlink) {
            console.log(hyperlink);
            expect(testDataLInks).toContain(hyperlink);
        });
    });
});
```

});

1) First identify the elemetns with tag 'a', and take them into a list.

2) For each element you get the hyperlink by using getAttribute('href').

3) Assert the hyperlink with the list of test data that you have.